# How can I see in SMS app my messages sent from within my app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, mkmapview

Suppose i got my friend's location in sms..What link should i send in the sms so that on clicking that link, it would open that lat/long in my MapApp.. how can i open that location in my MapApp?? Please help me as soon as possible...Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which app do you want to open, your app or Apple's Maps app?

Comment: Suppose i got my friend's location in sms..Then how can i open that location in my MapAp?? Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First follow the "Launching Your Own Application via a Custom URL Scheme" from the link http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html. After that the application will be opened from the SMS link.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. If you include a URL that points to a Google Maps request, and your friend taps that URL, it will open up in Google Maps. You can see the format for the URL documented in [Map Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an [geosms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoSMS) (available in android, not sure if they have it in ios) which does what you describe in your question. Read [GeoSMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoSMS) and [Geo URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI) to get an idea where to start.